# Laravel 5.5 - Envio de E-mail / Arquivo Env

Tags: laravel-5

Estou migrando um site que tenho para Laravel 5 e me deparei com um problema.

Para enviar email no Laravel eu preciso preencher manualmente os dados de porta usuário e host no arquivo .env

Como no meu site eu tenho uma interface para o usuário interagir, eu acabo recebendo esses dados criptografados do banco de dados, por esse fato, se torna inviável preencher os dados `MAIL_HOST, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD` manualmente no arquivo .ENV, Por isso pergunto:

É possível repassar isso para o arquivo ENV ou acessar uma função na qual eu consiga passar diretamente esses dados e conseguir disparar o email?

Comment: Se esses dados tiverem no banco de dados, basta criar um `Model` para capturar e utilizar na função de envio.

Comment: Mas qual é a função de envio ? A rotina de envio funciona.. os dados estão em uma model, eu preciso pegar os dados só isso, como vou passar os dados para o laravel enviar sem ser pelo arquivo env? É isso q não sei fazer !

Comment: Se possível edite sua pergunta e coloque como você está enviando esses dados.

Comment: problema resolvido.. postei uma respota..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma:

O Lavavel possui uma forma de acesso na qual podemos setar em tempo de execução as propriedades diretamente usando **config**.

Como eu queria preencher as configurações de email,
precisei acessar as propriedades responsáveis pelo email que fica em **Config\Mail.php.**

Através do item acima consegui identificar o nome de cada propriedade para aí setar os valores dessa forma:

```
    config(['mail.host' => 'smtp.meusite.com.br']);
    config(['mail.port' => '587']);
    config(['mail.username' => 'usuario@meusite.com.br']);
    config(['mail.password' => 'senha']);
```

Abaixo o link da documentação para quem precisar!

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values